# How can I convert a single integer representing days into pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column "time" of float numbers, representing days from 0 to 8, and one more column with other data. The time step is not continuous.

```
time_clean = np.arange(0, 8, 0.1)
noise = [random.random()/10 for n in range(len(time_clean))]
time = time_clean + noise

data = [random.random()*100 for n in range(len(time_clean))]

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": time, "data":data})
df.head()

      data      time
0  89.965240  0.041341
1  95.964621  0.109215
2  70.552763  0.232596
3  74.457244  0.330750
4  13.228426  0.471623
```

I want to resample and interpolate the data to every 15 minutes, (`15/(60*24)` days).

I think the most efficient way to do this would be using the `resample` method of pandas dataframes, but in order to do that I need to convert the time column into a `timestamp`, and make it the index.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? Is it possible to transform an `int` to `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first convert column `time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

Also I think the best is add one new row with `0` for always starts resample from `0` (if `0` is not in `time` column it starts from minimal `time` value)

```
df.loc[-1] = 0
df.time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='d')
df = df.sort_values('time').set_index('time').resample('15T').ffill()
print (df.head(20))
               data
time               
00:00:00   0.000000
00:15:00   0.000000
00:30:00   0.000000
00:45:00   0.000000
01:00:00   0.000000
01:15:00   0.000000
01:30:00  50.869889
01:45:00  50.869889
02:00:00  50.869889
02:15:00  50.869889
02:30:00  50.869889
02:45:00  50.869889
03:00:00  50.869889
03:15:00   8.846017
03:30:00   8.846017
03:45:00   8.846017
04:00:00   8.846017
04:15:00   8.846017
04:30:00   8.846017
04:45:00   8.846017
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!